# how to design the footer with svg image that has waves style?

Tags: html, css

i want the waves styles like in the image but i could not able to make the style. i have the exact `svg` image that display in the image below. I use `html` and `css` for this.

```css
   .footer-waves {
      background: green url('wavesBotttom.svg') 100% 100% no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
    <footer class="footer-waves"></footer>
```

i tried this but cannot able to make the background like this. i only want waves style and that svg file was given in the css code.